# Running docker container with ubuntu:16.04 actually runs ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I was trying to run a docker container with ubuntu:16.04 (on a ubuntu 18.04 machine) with the following command:

```
docker run -i -t --name ubuntu ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

Running this command attaches me to a container. But when I check the kernel information with `uname -a`, it shows that the current kernel is Ubuntu 18.04.  Following is the result I get:

```
Linux 1ac6c3456e2a 5.3.0-40-generic #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Docker uses host OS kernel, there is no custom or additional kernel inside container. All containers which run on a machine are sharing this "host" kernel.

Please read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/889472/docker-containers-have-their-own-kernel-or-not) for more detail.

So **#32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020** in the output of `uname -a` is actually the Kernel version of the host machine.

To verify that you are running Ubuntu 16:04, run `cat /etc/os-release`. It will provide you details about your OS.